# Passing data without intent when using finish() - Android

Tags: android

When starting a new activity (MyActivity2) I can pass data with .addExtra(). After opening MyActivity2 I can call getExtra() and my data is right where I want it. My question -  After calling finish() on MyActivity2, I want to pass data to  MyActivity1. What is the proper way to pass data when just drilling back to the previous activity like this? A static variable seems to work but from what I have read, they are not part of OOP. What are my options?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `startActivityForResult()`. Check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10407159/how-to-manage-startactivityforresult-on-android) question.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. I wasn't aware of startActivityForResult(). Thanks